# Why won't windows let me have access to these virtual machines and how to get access?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-xp, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

No matter which iso files I download, regardless of the site I get it from, when I make an ISO file, I get this error:

> Error while powering on: VMware Player cannot connect to the virtual machine. Make sure you have rights to run the program, access all directories the program uses, and access all directories for temporary files.
>
> Failed to connect pipe to virtual machine: The system cannot find the file specified.

Before that it gives me another error, telling me to collect support data. I do and it makes no difference. It didn't used to do this for Kali Linux, but it will do it for both my Windows VMs. Now it does it for Kali and even Ubuntu. Why is it doing this? How do I fix this?

Comment: We'd need to know the site so we could try one. Exactly how are you trying to use these ISOs? Could you at least post a screen snap of your virtual machine's "settings"?

Comment: I try to download isos from several sites. Prominently, this one:

http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/

But I've also tried several other sites. I know that one is prebuilt virtual machines but I've tried several other sites with actual ISOs and it won't make a difference.

Comment: Now its doing the same thing with my Kali. It's like it doesn't want me using any VMs.

Comment: I updated the above to fit the current situation better.

Answer (score 1):

This should have nothing to do with an iso.

Normally the error occurs if VMWare locks something and cannot access it later.

You can try:

1. Reboot host system.
2. Run VmWare as Adminstrator /root
   or
3. Create a new virtual machine and attach the old vhd to it.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer. I just refreshed my PC (since it was a new PC), and it let me access everything after I reinstalled VMWare Workstation with a universal serial key.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that finally worked for me was:

- Go to **add or remove programs" (aka Apps & Features)
- Click "modify"
- Select "repair" on both the (x64) and (x86) versions of my Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable ver. 14.24.28126.4